# Use "this" in a function declaration (as a default parameter)

Tags: c++

Can I use `this` in a function declaration (part of a class) to specify a default argument?

Example:

```
class Object {

    Object::Object(){
        this->color = rand(); //let's pretend that rand() will generate a random integer and that fillBg can draw a color given an integer.
    }

    Object::fillBg(int color = this->color){
        //do stuff
    }

}
```

...so when an object is made of this `Object` class, a random color will be painted as the background of the object (unless you pass another color).

Comment: why don't you try it out and see?

Comment: @Ashalynd already did, it says I can't use "this" like this, so I'm asking here just to be sure if I can't use it like this in any way, or if there is some dark hack I can use.

Comment: What is the problem to set default parameter to -1 and then check `if ( color == -1 ) color = this->color` in the body of method?

Comment: @i486 no problem, I was just asking if this is possible

Comment: Ok, the answer of your question is "No" :)

Comment: @i486 -1 could be a valid parameter too, the this solution won´t work.

Comment: After correcting bad syntax: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f07e70a74ee12b2f

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, you can't. The standard prohibits it explicitly:

> The keyword `this` shall not be used in a default argument of a member function.

(C++11, [dcl.fct.default]/7)

I believe this rule makes sense because initialization of default arguments takes place in the context of the caller, not the callee. (And in the caller's context there may be no such thing as `this`, or it might be a different object, which could cause confusion.)

One possible solution is just to overload.

```
Object::fillBg(int color) {
    // ...
}

Object::fillBg() {
    fillBg(this->color);
}
```

Comment: Why not just say that default-arguments are evaluated in callee context? What would it break? Or said differently, why wouldn't it make sense?

Comment: @Deduplicator Consistency with other arguments, I think. "The initialization and destruction of each parameter occurs within the context of the
calling function." ([expr.call]/4)

Answer (score 6):

I assume there is a variable color in the class too, else everything makes no sense.

The answer is no, this is not possible. But you can use

```
Object::fillBg()
{
    fillBg(this->color);
}
Object::fillBg(int color)
{
    //use color
}
```

Comment: @IdeaHat Thanks for the improvement :)

Answer (score 2):

No, this is not allowed. [dcl.fct.default]/p8

> The keyword this shall not be used in a default argument of a member function. [ Example:
>
> ```
>  class A {
>      void f(A* p = this) { } // error
>  };
> ```
>
> — end example ]

Anyway, it doesn't matter because of what [dcl.fct.default]/p9 says:

> Similarly, a non-static member shall not be used in a default argument, even if it is not
>   evaluated, unless it appears as the *id-expression* of a class member access expression (5.2.5) or unless it is used to form a pointer to member (5.3.1). [ Example: the declaration of `X::mem1()` in the following example is ill-formed because no object is supplied for the non-static member `X::a` used as an initializer.
>
> ```
> int b;
> class X {
>     int a;
>     int mem1(int i = a); // error: non-static member a
>     // used as default argument
>     int mem2(int i = b); // OK; use X::b
>     static int b;
> };
> ```
>
> The declaration of `X::mem2()` is meaningful, however, since no object is needed to access the static member `X::b`.